# Flyway Community: Does "Undo" migration filenames existing at all in "locations", cause "Unrecognized migration name format" error? Unhelpful stderr

Tags: migration, flyway, undo

I have a pretty simple question.  On my Flyway Community repo, if I have any "Undo Migrations" (U1.1__description1undo.h2.sql, for example) example files simply *existing at all* in my "locations" folder, will that cause Flyway to fail will errors like "Invalid SQL filenames found" and "Unrecognised migration name format"?

I'm not wanting to even run "flyway undo" here, I'm talking about simply having "U" example files sitting around in my application folder, while I try to do things like "flyway info", "flyway validate", and "flyway migrate".

I have flyway.validateMigrationNaming=true in this circumstance.

That seems like a very wasted opportunity for flyway community edition to A) print a helpful error message "'U' Migrations are only supported in Flyway Teams".  Or for Flyway Community, on its own, to simply have a setting that B) allows it to choose to ignore "U" files altogether, or C) print out a warning and not fail since its Community Edition, and that's a paid feature.

Either way, the Flyway Community Edition command-line user experience for this is unideal and the current behavior takes the most simple concept (having a file that starts with "U" in the name) and prints out weird, uninterpretable error messages to be printed out.

Example log:
`

```
...
DEBUG: Validating V1.0__description0.h2.sql
DEBUG: Validating U1.1__description1undo.h2.sql
DEBUG: Validating V1.1__description1.h2.sql
DEBUG: Validating V1.2__description2.h2.sql
ERROR: Unexpected error
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Invalid SQL filenames found:
Unrecognised migration name format: U1.1__description1undo.h2.sql
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resource.ResourceNameValidator.validateSQLMigrationNaming(ResourceNameValidator.java:59)
    at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:144)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.info(Flyway.java:193)
    at org.flywaydb.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:179)
```

`

I expected to be able to have example "U1.1__description1undo.h2.sql" files sit around in my Flyway Community DB migration folder (not being used, just having them exist), without esoteric and weird error messages being triggered.

I'm not trying to use the command "Flyway Undo" (which is a Flyway Teams feature), nor do I want to in this circumstance.  I'm just wanting to have example "U" file prepped & ready so that when & if we try out Flyway Teams, we're ready to try out some of the more advanced paid flyway functionality.